# reset of full-speed USB device using ehci-pci kills Bluetooth

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 18.10

I am on Ubuntu 18.10

Since some weeks my Bluetooth mouse stops working. Each time when this happens I have this message in my logs:

```
[ 8555.431968] usb 1-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

after that Bluetooth is dead and a "sudo service bluetooth restart" fails.

```
[ 9194.210589] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[ 9196.226580] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0406 tx timeout
[ 9199.458612] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 9207.682541] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

the only way to get Bluetooth back is reboot.

What can I do to get BT working reliable ?

Answer (score 1):

This means there is some kind of issue with the underlying USB bus. I have seen this happen with USB cameras or mice that had damaged wires or internals. Essentially, something at a very low level is sending or receiving corrupted USB data, so as a last resort Linux resets the USB connection.

To complicate things further some systems implement their Bluetooth controllers are USB controllers, which is likely why its' affecting both.

For technical details see this [Unix Exchange post](https://superuser.com/a/1107610/33546).

It's possible that updating your PC firmware could resolve the issue. I would look at the available new versions of your BIOS from your manufacturer and see if they mention improvements in USB or Bluetooth stability. The process of upgrading the firmware/BIOS should involve putting a file onto a USB thumb drive and rebooting, but it depends on your system. There is also the `fwupdate` command in Ubuntu which can tell you if new firmware exists possibly for the Bluetooth device itself.

Assuming this keeps happening you can at the very least try reloading the kernel module associated with Bluetooth to avoid a complete reboot. You'll have to determine which module is being used for Bluetooth, you likely can get that from `lsmod | grep blue`, and then you can do the following to reload the module instead of rebooting:

```
sudo rmmod name_of_module
sudo modprobe name_of_module
```

If you get an error trying to `rmmod` you can try passing the `-f` option to "force" the removal of the module, although with anything in Linux once you start "forcing" something may be creating additional problems and your mileage may vary.

Comment: fwupdate is not supported on my machine. I also believe that the USB bus is the source of the problem. Looking around I found the following kernel parameter `btusb.enable_autosuspend=n` which I have added and until now it seems to work.

Comment: I concur with @KristopherIves - My mouse was starting to freeze and eventually lock up.  The only fix was to either reboot or unbind and then rebind ehci.  Eventually, I got tired and while watching the logs, I started jiggling the cable right where it enters the mouse enclosure and saw the resets while doing this.  I cut the cable at the bend and re crimped - what can I say, I love the mouse.  I've had it since 2011 - hard to let go. All good now.